# Unable to enable receive locations (many of them)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Whenever I try to enable these receive locations, I get the sql time out error. Moreover there are many service instances and messages which are in active state or Dehydrated (Queued awaiting processing).

### TITLE: BizTalk Server Administration

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-2&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The wait operation timed out

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

I had tried restarting the host instances, but it did not work. The environment is a clustered server. There looks like no performance issue:  no memory or cpu spikes.

Comment: And these are SQL Receive Locations?  You are going to have to give more details about the receive locations, e.g. how they are configured.  If they were working previously or are new ones that have never worked.

Comment: Did you have a look to the event viewer ? Wich adapter is used by these locations ?